Updating a slice from a goroutine
I'm having trouble trying to work out how to update a slice from parallel goroutines. I initially came up with this code (that I knew wasn't the correct way to do it!):
func main() {

    var dwpList = []int {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    var mmrpList []int
    
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ch1 := make(chan int)

    cores := 4

    wg.Add(cores + 1)

    for i := 0; i < cores; i++ {
        go func1(&mmrpList, ch1, &wg)
    }

    iterateSamples(dwpList, ch1, &wg)

    close(ch1)

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(mmrpList)

}

func iterateSamples(dwpList []int, ch1 chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    defer wg.Done()

    for _, dwp := range dwpList {
    
        ch1 <- dwp
    }
}

func func1(mmrpList *[]int, ch1 <-chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    defer wg.Done()

    for dwp := range ch1 {
    
        *mmrpList = append(*mmrpList, dwp)
    }
}

Obviously this doesn't work as there are multiple goroutines appending to the slice at the same time.
The problem is, whenever I try to move the append into it's own function controlled by extra channels, waitgroups, etc. I always run into compile or 'deadlock' issues (which aren't always deadlocks but a wg Wait or Done issue), or it reverts back to being single-threaded.
Can you please guide me as to how this should be achieved?

I tried to apply Burak's style to my code, and came up with this:
func main() {

    var dwpList = []int {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    var mmrpList []int
    
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ch1 := make(chan int)
    ch2 := make(chan int)

    cores := 4

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        // Get data
        for _, dwp := range dwpList {
            ch1 <- dwp
        }
        close(ch1)
    }()

    for i := 0; i < cores; i++ {

        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            // Do stuff then pass data on
            for dwp := range ch1 {
                ch2 <- dwp
            }
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch2)
    }()

    for dwp := range ch2 {
        mmrpList = append(mmrpList, dwp)
    }

    fmt.Println(mmrpList)

}

Finally! (Had to make the write to ch1 a single process though)

Close ch1 when you return from the first goroutine. The second goroutine is stuck waiting to read from it.

@Burak Sorry, no - still not getting it. I've simplified the reply example once again, so now the only goroutines are writing 1 -> 2. Closing ch1 after writing to it. Still deadlock.

No, you oversimplified it. Your previous solution was ok, the only thing you needed to do was to close the channel after writing everything. It deadlocks now, because you are writing to a channel, and there are no goroutines reading from it.

@Burak Got there in the end, but I don't know how it could have been done if I'd kept in the multiple goroutine writes to ch1?

Try solving it and ask a separate question if you cannot do it

What you are looking for might be pipelines (Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    dwpList := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

    ch1 := iterateSamples(dwpList)

    mmrpList := func1(ch1)

    fmt.Println(mmrpList)
}

func iterateSamples(dwpList []int) <-chan int {
    ch1 := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for _, dwp := range dwpList {
            ch1 <- dwp
        }
        close(ch1)
    }()

    return ch1
}

func func1(ch1 <-chan int) []int {
    var mmrpList []int

    for dwp := range ch1 {
        mmrpList = append(mmrpList, dwp)
    }

    return mmrpList
}

This reads pretty clearly and is lock free.
If you want to collect the input from multiple sources (or distribute the work onto multiple workers), see chapter “Fan-out, fan-in.”
While locks are not bad per se, having multiple goroutines competing for the same resource (a slice) guarded with a lock can have worse performance that dedicating a single goroutine to the job.
See also “Rethinking Classical Concurrency Patterns.”

When you want to iterate over multiple lists, just use merge from “Fan-out, fan-in” (Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    dwpList1 := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    dwpList2 := []int{11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}

    ch1 := iterateSamples(dwpList1)
    ch2 := iterateSamples(dwpList2)

    ch := merge(ch1, ch2)

    mmrpList := func1(ch)

    fmt.Println(mmrpList)
}

These patterns are easily composable.

It looks as though part of my problem was (is!) where to locate the close. In your example (if I've got this right), trying to make iterateSamples run in parallel causes one goroutine to close the channel before the others have finished running. That was my dilemma. Putting it after the wait caused a deadlock. From my point of view, it was Catch-22. Thanks for the links - I hadn't found those.

If you want to make multiple iterateSamples, start multiple goroutines with a separate channel each and use a merge from “fan-in”.

you can implement slice with sync.mutex package to avoid race condition and concurrent access to shared resources in multiple goroutines

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type myList struct {
    list []int
    lock *sync.Mutex
}

func (l *myList) Add(number int) {
    l.lock.Lock()
    defer l.lock.Unlock()
    l.list = append(l.list, number)
}

func (l myList) GetList() []int {
    l.lock.Lock()
    defer l.lock.Unlock()
    return l.list
}

func main() {
    dwpList := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
    mmrpList := myList{
        list: []int{},
        lock: new(sync.Mutex),
    }

    var listchan = make(chan int)
    defer close(listchan)

    for i := 0; i <= 5; i++ {
        go func() {
            for num := range listchan {
                mmrpList.Add(num)
            }
        }()
    }

    for _, num := range dwpList {
        listchan <- num
    }

    fmt.Println(mmrpList.GetList())
}

in this code you can add item to the slice in 5 concurrent goroutines and fetch the list at the end after finishing add items.

The slice is shared among multiple goroutines. You have to ensure mutual exclusion when you  update the slice. In other words, this should work:
func func1(mmrpList *[]int, mmrpLock *sync.Mutex, ch1 <-chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    defer wg.Done()

    for dwp := range ch1 {
        mmrpLock.Lock()
        *mmrpList = append(*mmrpList, dwp)
        mmrpLock.Unlock()
    }
}

That also means you have to create one mutex and pass it to all goroutines as well.
That said, this is usually not how you want to do it. There is simply no point in having multiple goroutines adding to a single slice. This is not something you want to run concurrently due to the sequential nature of appending to a slice.
What you can do is having a single goroutine that appends to the slice, but multiple goroutines writing to a channel, something like:
// Start multiple goroutines to write to ch1
wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}
for i:=0;i<n;i++ {
   wg.Add(1)
   go func() {
      defer wg.Done()
      generateData(ch1)
   }()
}

// Wait for all writers to complete and close the channel
go func() {
   wg.Wait()
   close(ch1)
}()

for data:=range ch1 {
   mmrpList=append(mmrpList,data)
}

This way, you would not need to serialize access to the slice.
